# Implementing reusable components in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I am trying to implement reusable components in flex 3. I have tab navigator which will be dynamic.In the screen i have a button with click operation a tab navigator wiht vbox as child will be created and in vbox i have one textbox which takes input information from user.

I have a show button beside the click button. when a user click show button and if the four tabs are opened we need to put all of the textboxes of the VBox to the Text Area.

here is my code.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">


    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import Repeat;
    private var input:String;

    private var i:int=0;
            private function addNextTab(event:Event):void {
                tabs.addChild(new Repeat("Tab"));
            }
            private function show()
            {

                var child:DisplayObject;

            for(i=0;i<tabs.numChildren;i++)
            {


      child=tabs.getChildAt(i);
              input=TextInput(child.getChildAt(0)).text;//error
              textArea.text=textArea.text+input;
            }
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:TabNavigator id="tabs" width="100%" height="100%">

    </mx:TabNavigator>

        <mx:TextArea id="textArea"/>
    <mx:Button label="Add Next Tab" click="addNextTab(event)" />
    <mx:Button label="Show Values" click="show()" />

    </mx:Application>
```

the one line is showing the errors. I am intial learner on the flex. But i tried to learn and do my own. 
here is my Repeat.as

```
package {
import mx.containers.VBox;
import mx.controls.Label;
import mx.controls.TextInput;

public class Repeat extends VBox {
    public function Repeat(name:String) {
        label = name;


    }

    override protected function createChildren():void {
        super.createChildren();

        var box:VBox = new VBox();
        var t1:TextInput = new TextInput();

        box.addChild(t1);

        addChild(box);
    }
}
}
```

i have to access the text box information of all the tabs and put it in textArea.

can any body help me.?

BTW: It is flex 3 application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make text a public property and don't create a nested VBox to add it to.  You are already extending VBox, so just addChild.. like this:

```
package {
    import mx.containers.VBox;
    import mx.controls.Label;
    import mx.controls.TextInput;

    public class Repeat extends VBox {

        public var text:TextInput;

        public function Repeat(name:String) {
            label = name;
        }

        override protected function createChildren():void {
            super.createChildren();
            text = new TextInput();
            addChild(text);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: show to access it.

```
child = tabs.getChildAt(i) as Repeat;
child.text.text = someNewValue;
```

Comment: It is saying error that access of undefined propety child..that said,when we put the text as public variable will it effect any thing on the reusability..if you see my program it is generating same componenent again and again and when the user clicks the show button it iteratively adds all of the reusable to component text values to textArea..

Comment: it will work exactly as you want it.  the error is because you set this - var child:DisplayObject;  then used the code I gave you child = tabs.getChildAt(i) as Repeat;  you need to set this:  var child:Repeat;

Comment: an the reusability is correct.  each call to new Repeat("Tab") creates a separate Repeat object with its OWN TextInput called text.  That's how come every Button has a label.  One Button class with public var label (not exactly but same point)... as many new Button()s as you please.  :)

Comment: actually i have main goal of form collection ( there are 4 text boxes with the user enters and 4 tabs so 16 values and i need to get the information of all 16 values to another screen...so i tried this one as example..it is working properly..so i can forward my work..can you give any suggesion on my main goal...i have to still implement some other improvements on my goal..if you do not mind please keep an eye on this page..i will work on my own..i will ask only if i really struck.thanks